# Excel not responding after running macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I used the below code to copy a column from one sheet to another and then replace the blank cells with a Null value:

```
'Copying If Employee
sourceSheet.Activate
Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Copy
destSheet.Activate
Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, 7)).PasteSpecial

For Each cell In Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, 5))
If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
    cell.Value = "No"
End If
```

When I replace the for statement with `Range("E2", Cells(500,5))` it is working fine.

What might be the problem? I was unable to figure out. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you do a msgbox(Rows.Count) to find out what value is being set. I would try to avoid using Rows.Count. There are much better methods of finding the end of a worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
For Each cell In Range("E2", Cells(destSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5))
If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
    cell.Value = "No"
End If
```

Or more elegantly (and probably a lot faster),

```
Dim calcStatus As XlCalculation
calcStatus = Application.Calculation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each cell In Range("E2:E" & destSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
    cell.Value = "No"
End If    

Application.Calculation = calcStatus
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Be carefull when using ´UsedRange.Rows.count´ to get the last row.  If your first cell used was E100 and the las was E115, this method will give you row 15 as result instead of row 115.

Comment: This is true. You can find more robust solutions to LastRow finding on Sid's website: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Answer (score 8):

Excel 2007 has 1,048,576 rows.

1. Your For each loop has to go through a million cells and each time it has to load a cell (with all its properties) into the memory.  This constant loading and unloading of cell objects is very resource consuming.
2. Each time you assign the value `No` to a cell, Excel recalculates the sheet, refreshes the screen and might trigger worksheets/workbook/cell events. All this before evaluating the next cell to the next cell.  Unless you have a HUGE amount of data, this will be happening a couple hundred tousand times in this example.

500 cells is a much smaller number and can be handled without problem.

**Edit:**

Geting the last row.

If you want to get the last **visible** row with data, then use:

```
With Workbooks(myWorkbook).Worksheets(myWorksheet)
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

If you want to get the last row with data, regardless of it being visible or hidden, then use:

```
With Workbooks(myWorkbook).Worksheets(myWorksheet)
   LastRow =.Range("E2").EntireColumn.Find("*", .Cells(1, .Range("E2").Column), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

For more info [Rondebruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/last.htm) has a good site with more info about geting the las row/column.

Comment: +1 bob on - @Pramod CaBieberach is totally correct - you are looping through a huge amount of data so the application is grinding to a halt - follow one of the code examples in the other solutions for a way to avoid the sledgehammer approach

Answer (score 2):

As Cabierberach rightly points out, your current routine loops over 1M lines. In addition to his and JustinJDavies solution, consider this hack:

Instead of setting the values `0` to  `No`, you simply can change the format if the cells to display `No` every time the value is `0`. This can be done without a macro by applying this custom format to the cells: `0,-0,"No",@`. You might need to replace the `0`with your default format - see [this link](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm) for a detailed description of the custom number format.

If you want to do this in VBA, this line will suffice:

```
Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).CustomFormat = "0,0,""No"",@"
```