# Excel VBA Macro Not Responding After Running Over Night

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I built a random number generator in excel which outputs to another column in another sheet in the workbook. The macro has a cut off at cell A1,000,000. When I run it throughout the day while I'm working I can get close to 200,000 rows of output. When I run it over night and come back in the morning, it's frozen (Not Responding) which I think means it just worked itself into freezing before hitting the cut off.

I took a look at some other posts but they didn't quite answer my questions
([Excel Not Responding During Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063828/excel-not-responding-during-macro))
([Excel not responding after running macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054657/excel-not-responding-after-running-macro)).

Is there any way I can get it out of Not Responding and just disable the macro and take a look at the output?

Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

Do
    Do

      Do
      Range("H12").Select
      Range("H12").ClearContents

      Loop Until Range("K10") = "MATCH" And Range("K11") = "GOOD"

      Range("H2:H8").Select
      Selection.Copy
      Range("P1").Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,    SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
      Range("P1:P5").Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NUMBER GENERATOR").sort.SortFields.Clear
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NUMBER GENERATOR").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
      "P1:P5"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
      xlSortNormal
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NUMBER GENERATOR").sort
      .SetRange Range("P1:P5")
      .Header = xlGuess
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
  End With


    Loop Until Range("P11") = "GOOD" And Range("P12") = 1


 Range("P9").Select
 Selection.Copy


 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
 Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,    Transpose:=False


 Sheets("NUMBER GENERATOR").Select
 Range("H12").Select

Loop Until Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000000") <> ""

End Sub
```

Comment: one place to start is to add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning, work directly with object (remove `.Select` statements), for example `Range("H2:H8").Copy destination:= Range("P1")` and `Range("P9").Copy destination:= Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`, and also qualify all Ranges with the specific sheet. In some cases you do this, already. This may help free of resource usage that may be causing it to freeze.

Comment: For debugging purposes you can maintain a counter variable and have a line like `If counter Mod 1000 = 0 Then DoEvents` in the inner-loop so that it will respond to break in the VBA editor. But -- if it takes you hours to process a million rows, you probably need a different approach, one that doesn't use select so much.

Comment: One other suggestion which may help is to set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` then only place a `calculate` option at the specific lines where you need the data to re-calculate. This is a bit of a guess since I think I know what you are doing, but am not 100% sure.

Comment: You can use this code without selecting anything, also would you be able to sort at the end of the code instead of constantly?

Comment: @Davesexcel I need to sort mid code because it would be a lot harder to do at the end. I'm trying a bunch things to get it out of Not Responding before I End Task it and start over rewriting the code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman In Range("P9"), I have a concatenate formula that I pasted as values into Sheet 1. Is there a way to do that in your corrected code? It helps a lot with the speed but doesn't quite get what I need. `Range("P9").Copy destination:= Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: @plankton: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1).Value = Range("P9").Value`

Comment: @plankton - another thing I see in your code is that you clear and add sort fields in each loop. If you add the sort field before the loop, all you need to do is `apply` it (the With Block part) each time you want to sort. You can also set the `Header` argument to `xlYes` or `xlNo` depending on your needs. In this way Excel doesn't have to waste resources "guessing" if you have headers.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Sorry, I'm a total n00b with VBA. I changed `Header` to `xlNo` but I'm not entirely sure how I would set up the sort fields before the loop.

Comment: @plankton - move the line that clears the sort and the line that adds it outside of the first Do Loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` is almost never needed in VBA. For example, the two lines

```
Range("H12").Select
Range("H12").ClearContents
```

can be replaced simply by:

```
Range("H12").ClearContents
```

More importantly, the 7 lines

```
Range("H2:H8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("P1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,    SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("P1:P5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

can be replaced by the single line

```
Range("P1:P7").Value = Range("H2:H8").Value
```

Similar remarks hold for other uses of `Select`. Making these changes and turning off screen-updating while the macro is running should help substantially (whether or not it will help enough is hard to say since it isn't clear what you are actually doing).

Comment: TY Sir! I'll let you know the result, if good I'll mark this as the answer.